# 7 day retention of archive files in unix

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I was supposed to remove the archive files that are at least 7days older or the files will be retain to the directory for about 7 days only. How can I execute it using shell script?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of files, what are the file names like, what is the directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

Using `find`

find /path/to/dir -mtime +7 -type f -exec rm {} \;

Answer (score 0):

I think everyday (use cron) you'll check which files are older than 7 days

check http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2006006